# pen drive not showing full capacity

Tags: usb

I'm trying to reformatted in Windows 7 by right clicking on the drive and selecting Format.... But the capacity only shows 144MB.

Is there something I can do to get the original size back? Maybe it got partitioned in a weird way?

Answer (score 0):

Whats is the capacity of the drive??
Secondly did you partition it earlier & how did you do it??
You can see the full capacity of the drive by getting to an elevated command prompt & then entering diskmgmt.msc (Disk Management)
Then in Disk Management look for removable drives & there you should be able to see your drive. If you see a large amount of unallocated space then most of the space might be unallocated & just some of the 100MBs partitioned & usable.

Answer (score 0):

Windows can normally only see the first partition of a USB drive. Provided you don't mind losing all contents of the USB drive I suggest you use a utility like [ImageUSB](http://www.osforensics.com/tools/write-usb-images.html), which can reset the MBR on a USB drive and make all the space available.